# Show an image in a simple html using an absolute url

Tags: html, image, google-app-engine, url, absolute

How can I embed/show and image only described with an absolute url (for instance http://www.myexample.com/myimage.jpg) in a basic html file? If that´s not possible, how would you do it? Is there any component to do it? I´ll use it on Google App Engine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  You most certainly can use an absolute URL to reference, well, anything from your HTML.  Is this not working for you?  Can you give an example of how it's not working?

Comment: Sorry, I thought img tag only offered relative URI´s. You´re right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed, an image referenced with an absolute URL will display identically to an image siting right in the same folder as the "basic html file".